# Can `D = (D→ D)_⊥` be solved in the domain of DCPOs with monotonic functions?

Tags: order-theory, denotational-semantics

A denotational semantic for the lambda calculus can be given by solving the domain equation

$$
D \simeq [D →_c D]_\bot
$$
in the category of $\omega$-complete CPOs, where $→_c$ denotes the space of $\omega$-continuous functions. The existence of an (initial) solution to this domain equation is a classic result by Scott (or Plotkin?).

One reason for the restriction to continuous functions here is that the equation
$$
D \simeq [D → D]_\bot
$$
(with $->$ denoting all functions) doesn’t have a solution, due to cardinality constraints.

But what about the middle ground where we allow monotonic, but possibly non-continuous functions:
$$
D \simeq [D →_m D]_\bot
$$
Does this have a solution in the category of partial ordered sets with monotone functions?

(Or maybe in the category of CPOs, but still allowing non-continuous functions in $\to_m$)

Comment: In <https://uu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1589443/FULLTEXT01.pdf> there is a theorem that “Every ω-continuous endofunctor on Dom has a fixed-point”. So maybe the question is: Is `D →m D` an ω-continous endofunctor in the category of domains?

Comment: Should this question be on cstheory? I am confused by the difference, but <https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/52415/fixpoint-of-a-functor-in-the-category-of-embeddings> certianly has a very similar feel.